# JSON Data Observer

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern

I wrote a small piece of code for observing changes on JSON object. Whenever there is a change in Object, it should trigger all the handlers with simplistic information about data change.

I am looking for improvements in the code. As I am struck with this pattern, could not think of better ideas of it. Please help.

How I am using this:

```
 var reactiveData = new Observer({a: [1,2, {b: 10}]});
 reactiveData.observe('a.3', function() {
    console.log('Changed');
 });
```

Implementation:

```
 var Observer = (function() {
    function Observer(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.handlers = {};
    }
    function clone(obj) { 
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
    }
    function setValue(object, path, value) {
        var a = path, o = object;
        if(!Array.isArray(path)) {
            a = path.split('.');
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            var n = a[i];
            if (n in o) {
                o = o[n];
            } else {
                o[n] = {};
                o = o[n];
            }
        }
        o[a[a.length - 1]] = value;
    }
    function getValue(object, path, getTrace) {
        var o = object, a = path, trace = [];
        if(!Array.isArray(path)) {
            path = path.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1');
            path = path.replace(/^\./, '');
            a = path.split('.');
        } else {
            a = path.slice(0);
        }
        while (a.length) {
            var n = a.shift();
            if (n in o) {
                o = o[n];
                if(getTrace) trace.push(o);
            } else {
                return getTrace ? trace : undefined;
            }
        }
        return getTrace ? trace : o;
    }
    function triggerHandlers(path, eventData) {
        var that = this, handlers = this.handlers;
        if(Array.isArray(path)) path = path.join('.');
        var pathHandlers = this.handlers[path] || [];
        pathHandlers.forEach(function(handler) {
            handler(eventData);
        });
    }
    var prototype = {
        constructor: Observer
    };
    prototype.setValue = function(path, value, options) {
        options = options || {};
        var trace = this.getValue(path, true) || [];
        if(!Array.isArray(path)) path = path.split('.');
        var data = trace[trace.length-2], d = this.data, p = path.slice(0);
        if(data) {
            d = data;
            p = p.slice(-1);
        }
        var previousValue = clone(getValue(d, p));
        setValue(d, p, value);
        // Lets trigger handlers now.
        for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            // var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(trace[i], i);
            var where = path.slice(i + 1);
            var evData = {
                prev: previousValue,
                new:  value,
                where: where
            };
            if(options.eventData) evData.original = options.eventData;
            where = where.length === 0 ? undefined : where;
            triggerHandlers.call(this, path.slice(0, i + 1), evData);
        }
    };
    prototype.getValue = function(path, getTrace) {
        return getValue(this.data, path, getTrace);
    };
    prototype.push = function(path, value) {
        var that = this, pathRef = getValue(that.data, path), options = {
            eventData: {
                type: 'push'
            }
        };
        var eventData = options.eventData;
        if(pathRef && Array.isArray(pathRef)) {
            eventData.position = pathRef.length;
            that.setValue(path + '.' + pathRef.length, value, options);
        } else if(pathRef === undefined) {
            eventData.position = 0;
            that.setValue(path, [value], options);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    prototype.unshift = function(path, value) {
        var pathRef = getValue(this.data, path), setVal = this.setValue, eventData = {
            type: 'unshift',
            position: 0
        };
        if(pathRef && Array.isArray(pathRef)) {
            pathRef.unshift(value);
            this.setValue(path + '.0', value, eventData);
        } else if(pathRef === undefined) {
            this.setValue(path, [value], eventData);
        }
    };
    prototype.insert = function(path, pos, value) {
        var pathRef = getValue(this.data, path), setVal = this.setValue, eventData = {
            type: 'insert',
            position: pos
        };
        if(pathRef && Array.isArray(pathRef)) {
            pathRef.splice(pos, 0, value);
            this.setValue(path + '.' + pos, value, eventData);
        } else if(pathRef === undefined) {
            this.setValue(path, [value], eventData);
        }
    };
    prototype.remove = function(path, pos) {
        var pathRef = getValue(this.data, path), setVal = this.setValue, eventData = {
            type: 'delete',
            position: pos
        };
        if(Array.isArray(pathRef)) {
            if(pos > 0 && pos < pathRef.length) {
                pathRef.splice(pos, 1);
                triggerHandlers.call(this, path, eventData);
            }
        } else if(typeof pathRef === "object") {
            delete pathRef[pos];
            triggerHandlers.call(this, path, eventData);
        }
    };
    prototype.observe = function(path, handler) {
        this.handlers[path] = this.handlers[path] || [];
        this.handlers[path][this.handlers[path].length] = handler;
    };
    prototype.unobserve = function(path, handler) {
        var pathHandlers = this.handlers[path] || [];
        var idx = pathHandlers.indexOf(handler);
        if(idx > -1) {
            pathHandlers.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    };
    Observer.prototype = prototype;
    return Observer;
})();
```

Comment: Could you kindly  show examples of how these functions  are called

Comment: I think you miss the *clone()* function, and maybe something is not work properly, like the *eventData.where*.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini Added clone method.

Comment: console.log() calls are quite expensive, and from by the looks of things you are calling it on every change so far. ( I get that it's for verifying functionality, however if you are having performance issues I would test it with some other action you can verify, and that doesn't have to call all the way out to debug interfaces)

Comment: @DJHenjin console.log is just for testing purpose.

Comment: Are you simply interested in comments on your implementation, or were you actually looking to use this code in a project?  Because if it's the latter, this feature is built into js via `Proxy`, and you should probably use that instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: I am willing to use it in my Project. Looking for better solution over this